# Chord $x+y=1$ Subtends $45^{\circ}$ at the centre

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

If the Chord $x+y=1$ Subtends $45^{\circ}$ at the centre of the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$, Find $a$

Method $1$:

We have radius=$a$

If $O$ is the centre and chord be $AB$ we have

$$\angle AOB =45$$

If $OM$ is drawn perpendicular to the chord we have:

$$\angle AOM=22.5$$

In $\Delta AOM$ we have

$$cos(22.5)=\frac{OM}{a}$$

$OM$ is perpendicular distance from $(0,0)$ to $x+y=1$ which is

$$OM=\left|\frac{0+0-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Hence we get $$a=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$$

Method $2.$

By Homogenization of line and curve we have:

$$x^+y^2=a^2(x+y)^2$$

$$(a^2-1)x^2+2xya^2+(a^2-1)y^2=0$$

This pair of straight lines subtends angle of $45^{\circ}$

We have formula that:

$$\tan (\theta)=\left|\frac{2\sqrt{H^2-AB}}{A+B}\right|$$

We have

$A=a^2-1=B$ and $H=a^2$

We get

$$1=\left|\frac{2\sqrt{a^4-(a^2-1)^2}}{2(a^2-1)}\right|$$

Simplifying we get

$$a^4-4a^2+2=0$$

Giving

$$a=\sqrt{2\pm \sqrt{2}}$$

Why in first Method, i could not get second answer?

Comment: What does this sentence mean: "If the Chord x+y=1 Subtends 45∘ at the centre of the circle" ?

Comment: Let the intersection points of the chord and the circle be $A$ and $B$. Then this means that $\angle AOB = 45º$.

Comment: in the second method, you need to reject $a=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}>1$, because $a<1$ to have $\angle AOB=45^\circ$. Note that the circle with radius $a=1$ passes through the x and y intercepts of the line $x+y=1$, that is $(0,1),(1,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that you couldn't get the second answer of the second method $\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}$ in the first method. It's that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}$ is *wrong* – drawing the associated circle and line and measuring the subtended angle gives you well over $90^\circ$. There is only one (positive) solution $a$.

Answer (score 1):

When $a=1$, the angle subtended is $90º$. This angle will continually decrease until the circle is tangent to the chord, giving a subtended angle of $0º$. Similarly, increasing $a$ will cause the subtended angle to be larger than $90º$, eventually approaching $180º$.

Therefore there is only one solution for $a$. If you get two solutions, you should substitute $a$ into the original equation to verify which solution makes sense.